# GEE Error: .setGeometry is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to replace the geometry of a feature with another geometry:

```
var new_feature = old_feature.setGeometry(g); //g is a geometry
```

When I get :

"old_feature.setGeometry is not a function" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, you need to explicitly cast `old_feature` to an `ee.Feature` because Earth Engine wasn't able to infer its type.

```js
var new_feature = ee.Feature(old_feature).setGeometry(g); //g is a geometry
```

To understand why Earth Engine couldn't infer the type of `old_feature`, you'll need to check the return type of the function that created it. For example:

- [`ee.FeatureCollection.first`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-first) returns an `Element`, not a `Feature`. This is because feature collections can store features *or* other feature collections, so Earth Engine doesn't know which will be returned<sup>*</sup>.
- [`ee.List.get`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-list-get) returns an `Object` because lists can store many different types.

If your object is created with an "ambiguous" return type like above, using an explicit cast tells Earth Engine to treat it as the defined type. If you're unsure of the return type and want to cast something for safety, the Code Editor will let you know if it's unneeded:

[image: Example of the unnecessary cast warning]

---

<sup>*</sup> This is different than [`ee.ImageCollection.first`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-first) which will always return an `Image` because that's the only thing that it can store.

Answer (score 1):

As @Aaron Zuspan correctly mentioned, in this case GEE is unable to infere the type of old_feature and therefore one needs to explicitely define the type of it :

```
var new_feature = ee.Feature(old_feature).setGeometry(g); //g is a geometry
```